# Pytorch DataLoader multiple data source

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to use Pytorch dataloader to define my own dataset, but I am not sure how to load multiple data source:

My current code:

```
class MultipleSourceDataSet(Dataset):
    def __init__ (self, json_file, root_dir, transform = None):
        with open(root_dir + 'block0.json') as f:
            self.result = torch.Tensor(json.load(f))

    self.root_dir = root_dir
    self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.result[0])

    def __getitem__ (self):
        None
```

The data source is 50 blocks under `root_dir = ~/Documents/blocks/`

I split them and avoid to combine them directly before since this is a very big dataset.

How can I load them into a single dataloader?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For [`DataLoader`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader) you need to have a single `Dataset`, your problem is that you have multiple `'json'` files and you only know how to create a `Dataset` from each `'json'` separately.
What you can do in this case is to use [`ConcatDataset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.ConcatDataset) that contains all the single-`'json'` datasets you create:

```
import os
import torch.utils.data as data

class SingeJsonDataset(data.Dataset):
    # implement a single json dataset here...

list_of_datasets = []
for j in os.path.listdir(root_dir):
    if not j.endswith('.json'):
        continue  # skip non-json files
    list_of_datasets.append(SingeJsonDataset(json_file=j, root_dir=root_dir, transform=None))
# once all single json datasets are created you can concat them into a single one:
multiple_json_dataset = data.ConcatDataset(list_of_datasets)
```

Now you can feed the concatenated dataset into `data.DataLoader`.

Comment: Thank you. This is a very detailed explanation. My problem is that if I concatenate all .json files, the file will become too big that it may eventually crash. 
However, I will still try this solution anyway. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there an update to this? I also am working with multiple files, and multiple datapoints per file.

Comment: @sealpuppy you do not concatenate the `json` files, but rather the datasets derived from them.

Comment: @SantoshGupta7 please do not ask questions in comments.

Comment: The problem with `ConcatDataset` is that it doesn't work with multiprocessing. It calls `len(ds)` on each dataset in it's initializer, so you end up loading every dataset in the main process.

Answer (score 4):

I should revise my question as 2 different sub-questions:

1. How to deal with large datasets in PyTorch to avoid memory error
2. If I am separating large a dataset into small chunks, how can I load multiple mini-datasets

   For **question 1**:

   PyTorch DataLoader can prevent this issue by creating mini-batches. [Here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/dealing-with-large-dataset-without-out-of-memory-error/19057) you can find further explanations.

   For **question 2**:

   Please refer to Shai's answer above.